# How to bind a key in a `generic` mode?

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode

Is there a way to bind a key in a mode defined using `define-generic-mode` such as `xmodmap-generic-mode`? Generic does not appear to create keymaps.

```
ELISP> (require 'generic-x)
generic-x
ELISP> (let (result)
     (mapatoms
      (lambda (sym)
        (when (and (boundp sym)
               (string-match-p "generic.*keymap$" (symbol-name sym)))
          (push sym result))))
     result)
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a [keymap variable as usual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html#index-keymaps-in-modes-2012), conventionally called `NAME-mode-map`. To use this keymap, the major mode startup function needs to call [`use-local-map`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Controlling-Active-Maps.html#index-use_002dlocal_002dmap-1905). If you're making your own call to `define-generic-mode`, pass a call to `use-local-map` in the `function-list` argument of [`define-generic-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generic-Modes.html#index-define_002dgeneric_002dmode-2067).

```el
(defvar some-generic-mode-map
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      …
      map)
  "Keymap for some mode.")
(define-generic-mode some-generic-mode
  nil nil nil
  '("\\.some\\'")
  #'((lambda () (use-local-map some-generic-mode-map)))
```

If you don't control the call to `define-generic-mode`, add a call to `use-local-map` to the generic mode hook. The mode startup function runs `NAME-mode-hook` (even though it doesn't define that symbol).

```el
(require 'generic-x)
(defvar xmodmap-generic-mode-map
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      …
      map)
  "Keymap for xmodmap generic mode.")
(defun use-xmodmap-generic-mode-map ()
  (use-local-map xmodmap-generic-mode-map))
(add-hook 'xmodmap-generic-mode-hook #'use-xmodmap-generic-mode-map)
```